# PHP usort hours with items after midnight

Tags: php, sorting

I have an event calendar where I'm usorting the events pulled back from the database. However the midnight items are technically earlier programmatically so they are showing up first in the list. How can I sort so that items midnight and later will show up at the end of the list?

```
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    //if after midnight (before 8am of next day)
    return strtotime($a['start_time']) >= strtotime('8:00') ? strtotime($a['start_time']) - strtotime($b['start_time']) : 1;
});
```

The way I have it now, they're sorting in the right order but the midnight or later items are showing up just after the first item. If I sort it normally without this "before 8am condition" they show up first.

Comment: you should store dates and times together, then they will sort properly. Also you can just sort this in the db query, probably faster

Comment: @nogad Think of repeated events that happen every day at a certain time.

Comment: @nogad Because of the setup this doesn't make sense for the user creating these events. These events are for a 3-day conference. We don't want the user to have to input the same date for a bunch of events. I have a radio selector for the day of the week and a time selector for the time.

Comment: you an add the date yourself then

Comment: @Barmar thats not what the OP is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time is in the early morning, add a day to it so it will be after evening times.

```
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    $oneday = 86400; // seconds in a day
    $cutoff = strtotime('8:00');
    $atime = strtotime($a['start_time']);
    if ($atime < $cutoff) {
        $atime += $oneday;
    }
    $btime = strtotime($b['start_time']);
    if ($btime < $cutoff) {
        $btime += $oneday;
    }
    return $atime - $btime;
});
```

Comment: This makes total sense. I would not have thought to do this. Thank you.